# Adjoint representation of the Lie bracket?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm reading [Bröckner and Dieck's *Representations of compact Lie groups*](https://ia600208.us.archive.org/22/items/springer_10.1007-978-3-662-12918-0/10.1007-978-3-662-12918-0.pdf) and
I have some problems in understanding the proof that the bracket defined via the adjoint representation indeed satisfies the properties of a Lie bracket in the abstract sense (page 18). I explain myself better, starting from the background and the work I have done so far.

Given $f:G\rightarrow H$, we define
\begin{align*}
L f:=T_ef:L G&\rightarrow L H\\
X &\mapsto X\circ f^*
\end{align*}where $f^*(\varphi):=\varphi\circ f$. Hence
\begin{equation*}
L f(X)\varphi=(X\circ f^*)\varphi=X(f^*(\varphi))=X(\varphi\circ f).
\end{equation*}Also, there is a canonical isomorphism between $LG$ and the vector space of left-invariant vector fields on $G$ and, in particular, $X\in LG$ can be seen as
\begin{align*}
X:G&\rightarrow TG\\
p &\mapsto \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\bigg|_0g\alpha^X(s),
\end{align*}where $\alpha^X$ is the integral curve of $X$ starting at $\alpha^X(0)=e$.

Now, for $g\in G$, let
\begin{align*}
c(g):G&\rightarrow G\\
x&\mapsto gxg^{-1}.
\end{align*}Then $c(g)$ is an automorphism hence we can consider
\begin{align*}
Lc(g):LG&\rightarrow L G\\
X&\mapsto X\circ c(g)^*
\end{align*}and we have that
\begin{equation*}
Lc(g)(X)\varphi=X(\varphi\circ c(g)).
\end{equation*}Now let
\begin{align*}
Ad:G&\rightarrow Aut(LG)\\
g&\mapsto Lc(g).
\end{align*}Then \begin{equation*}
(Ad(g)Y)\varphi=Lc(g)(Y)\varphi=Y(\varphi\circ c(g))=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_0(\varphi\circ c(g))\alpha^Y(t),
\end{equation*}hence
\begin{align*}
(Ad(\alpha^X(s))Y)\varphi&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_0(\varphi\circ c(\alpha^X(s)))\alpha^Y(t)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_0\varphi\biggl(c(\alpha^X(s))\alpha^Y(t)\biggr),
\end{align*}hence
\begin{align*}
Ad(\alpha^X(s))Y&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_0c(\alpha^X(s))\alpha^Y(t)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_0a(s,t),
\end{align*}where
\begin{equation*}
a(s,t):=c(\alpha^X(s))\alpha^Y(t)=\alpha^X(s)\cdot\alpha^Y(t)\cdot\alpha^X(-s).
\end{equation*}In particular $Ad(\alpha^X(s))Y\in LG$ as $Ad(\alpha^X(s))\in Aut(LG)$ and $Y\in LG$.

Now, let
\begin{align*}
ad:=LAd:LG&\rightarrow LAut(LG)=End(LG)\\
X&\mapsto X\circ Ad^*.
\end{align*}Then
\begin{align*}
ad(X)Y&=(X\circ Ad^*)(Y)\\
&=X(Y\circ Ad)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\bigg|_0(Y\circ Ad)\alpha^X(s)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\bigg|_0Y\biggl(Ad(\alpha^X(s))\biggr).
\end{align*}

So my question is:
Why\begin{equation*}
ad(X)Y=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\bigg|_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_0a(s,t)?
\end{equation*}Can we say that\begin{equation*}
Y\biggl(Ad(\alpha^X(s))\biggr)=Ad(\alpha^X(s))Y?
\end{equation*}

Thank you!